# Props not updated at Client side, when returning from server in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to get props, to show at the client side, but it's not showing.

The logic is i am trying to login, and when login fails, it should get the new props from the query object. It updates very well and i can see the update when I do "console.log" on the **getInitialProps** async method.

But the client page does not update to show the current value. Below is my code

**Login.js**

```
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import LoginPart from '../components/login'
import Link from 'next/link'
import {Component} from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import jsHttpCookie from 'cookie';
import {withRouter} from 'next/router'

const Login = (props) => (
    <Layout>
        <div>
            <div id="page-banner-area" className="page-banner-area section">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="page-banner-title text-center col-xs-12">
                            <h2>Login</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <!-- Problem >>> props.myprops shows nothing -->
            { "Modal value: "+ props.myprops }

            <!-- this is my Login Form part -->
            <LoginPart/>
       </div>
    </Layout>
)

Login.getInitialProps = async function({query}) {
   console.log("Initial property: "+ query.show)//this shows the updated value quite well
   return {myprops: query.show}
}

export default withRouter(Login)
```

**Server.js**

```
console.log("Login failed")

return app.render(req, res, '/login',{ show: "Badguy"})
```

Answer (score 0):

`getInitialProps` is a tricky one. When you do a SSR, it only run in server and when you do client side rendering, only runs on client side.

You are passing the queryString from `server` so it won't be available with `withRoute` in client side.

Comment: So how do I send data from server side to client side instantaneously. Like when I login, I want to set a variable that shows at once on the client from **getInitialProps** function. It seems **getInitialProps** only runs once the page is loaded....cant i have something set at once....like from **FETCH** method